# Lottery Program - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Have to create a lottery program, getting the random numbers and such easily enough. However I'm stumped. Essentially I have 2 buttons. One to display a checked list box with numbers 1-100, along with the 5 lotto numbers. I have a 2nd button that checks 2 things, to make sure that more than 5 numbers are not checked matching numbers. I'm lost on how to check for a match between the selected numbers between the RNG numbers.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub displayBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles displayBtn.Click
    Dim lottoNumbers(5) As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim randomGenerator As New Random(Now.Millisecond)

    'This will randomly select 5 unique numbers'
    Do While counter < 5
        number = randomGenerator.Next(0, 98)
        If Array.IndexOf(lottoNumbers, number) = -1 Then
            lottoNumbers(counter) = number
            counter += 1
        End If
    Loop

    'Display the lottery numbers in the label.'
    Label1.Text = String.Empty
    Array.Sort(lottoNumbers)
    For Each num As Integer In lottoNumbers
        Label2.Text = "Lottery Numbers"
        Label1.Text &= CStr(num) & " "
    Next num
    For x = 0 To 98
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(x + 1)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub checkBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBtn.Click
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim x As Integer

    'Checks to see if user checked more than 5'
    For x = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If (CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 5) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot select more than 5 numbers.")
            Return
        Else
            If (CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(x) = True) Then
                count = count + 1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(x))
            End If
        End If


    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not seeing anywhere in your code where you are attempting to compare the values?  You will need to get the values from the selected checkboxes and compare them with the values in the lottonumbers array.

Comment: Calling `New Random(Now.Millisecond)` is worse than calling `New Random()`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Plutonix - he's doing a `Array.IndexOf(lottoNumbers, number) = -1` to check uniqueness.

Comment: Ahh...missed that.  Sorry.  Still probably the wrong range

Comment: Do `Dim lottoNumbers As Integer() = Enumerable.Range(0, 98).OrderBy(Function (x) randomGenerator.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()` to select 5 unique numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm lost on how to check for a match between the selected numbers between the RNG numbers"?

Comment: Never ever pick 98 in this lottery.

Comment: @Enigmativity After the "Display" button is pressed, it fills the checked box list with numbers 1-99, along with 5 random numbers. My 2nd button "Checks" the selected numbers in the checked list box to see if they match the lotto numbers. At least it should but I have no clue how to do so since the array is in a different button method.

Comment: Then declare the array at the form level (along with the random object) so you can use it elsewhere.  The picker is getting numbers from 0 to 97 not 1-99.

Comment: @Leoinu - Plutonix has given you the answer..